# Get value from web.config into XSLT file

Tags: c#, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, web.config-transform

I have some values in my web.config that I want to access in my XSLT file. How do I do that?

I have done this to load the config file in my XSLT:

```
<xsl:variable name="config" select="document('..//Website//web.config')"/>

<p><xsl:value-of select="$config//appSettings/add[@key='Test']/@value"/>
</p>
```

After this I am stuck - nothing gets rendered.

Ok.I have done some changes.I have tried using a separate XML file and i am able to get value from the file in my variable.

```
    <xsl:apply-templates select="document('TestXML.xml')/test/Tag1">

    </xsl:apply-templates>

    <xsl:template match="Tag1">
      <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="@sName='myTest'">
        <span>
          <xsl:value-of select="@TestId" />
        </span>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>    
  </xsl:template>
```

I am still confused that while reading the web.config file(which is an xml file), i get an empty variable, but for a pure .xml file i get a value in my variable.

my Test.XML is this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<test>
  <Tag1 sName="myTest" TestId="328,329">
  </Tag1>

</test>
```

Please help me as to how could i work with a Web.config file with values under `<appsettings>` section.

Comment: Please show us what you have done so far to solve this issue.

Comment: @GauravDeochakke Please see my implementation in xslt file.I want a value from <appsettings> of web.config.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787862/pass-parameter-to-xslt-stylesheet

Comment: @AlG The thing is that why i am not getting in that config variable?

Comment: Your URI in `document()` is malformed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `document()` function should receive a valid URI scheme. Double-slashes `//` are used in XPath but are not valid path separators in an URI. If your `web.config` file is in the `Website` directory which is a sibling of the directory where your XSLT is located, the syntax should be:

```
<xsl:variable name="config" select="document('../Website/web.config')"/>
```

Assuming the rest of your stylesheet is correct, the XPath expression in the `value-of` should work if the structure of the XML inside your `web.config` matches it.

Comment: :I corrected as you said but i am still not getting the value in my variable considering that my web.config is correct.