# How do i get querystring value in xslt

Tags: .net, xml, url, xslt, query-string

How do i access querystring value in XSLT style sheet.

**Say For Example:**

my url is : `http://localhost:54279/SearchResults.aspx?trip=on&ad=1&ch=0&in=0`...

then how to get value of 1 from "ad"

I tried

```
 <xsl:param name="ad" select="ad" />
 <xsl:value-of select ="$ad"/>
```

But none of them worked..Any help please..

Answer (score 1):

If you passed the whole url as a parameter

```
<xsl:param name="url" />
```

then you could use combination of substring-before and substring-after functions

```
<xsl:variable name="ad" select="substring-before(substring-after($url,'&ad='),'&')" />
```

Comment: I'm not .net expert but following link http://stackoverflow.com/a/1521090/1324394 should be what you need.