# How to get an absolute path to the directory of the XSL file?

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xsd, filepath

My `Schema.xsd` file is located in the same directory with the `.xsl` file. In the `.xsl` file I would like to generate a link to `Schema.xsl` in the generated output. The generated output is located in different directories. Currently I do it like this:

```
   <xsl:template match="/">
     <root version="1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../Schema.xsd">
     <!-- . . . -->
```

However this forces the generated output to be located 3 levels under the directory of `Schema.xsd`. I would like to generate an absolute path to the schema in the output, so the output could be located anywhere.

**Update.** I use XSLT 1.0 (`XslCompiledTransform` implementation in .NET Framework 4.5).

Comment: Why don't you pass the directory of your XSL file as a parameter to the XSLT process?

Comment: @MarcusRickert, thank you for the hint. I am new to XSLT. I will have to research if it is possible to do in C# using `XslCompiledTransform`, because I run the xsl file this way.

Comment: This should be possible in `C#`.

Answer (score 3):

### XSLT 2.0 Solution

**Use the XPath 2.0 function, [resolve-uri()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-resolve-uri):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"
              omit-xml-declaration="yes"
              encoding="UTF-8"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <root version="1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="{concat(resolve-uri('.'), 'Schema.xsd')}">
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Yields, without parameter passing and regardless of the input XML:**

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      version="1.0"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file:/c:/path/to/XSLT/file/Schema.xsd"/>
```

Comment: +1. I use XSLT 1.0, however this answer could be useful for others who has simular problem in 2.0. Or may be I can switch to 2.0 later.

Answer (score 1):

This is a sketch of how to do it (also see [Passing parameters to XSLT Stylesheet via .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521064)).

In your C# code you need to define and use a parameter list:

```
XsltArgumentList argsList = new XsltArgumentList();
argsList.AddParam("SchemaLocation","","<SOME_PATH_TO_XSD_FILE>");

XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
transform.Load("<SOME_PATH_TO_XSLT_FILE>");

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("<SOME_PATH_TO_OUTPUT_XML>"))
{
    transform.Transform("<SOME_PATH_TO_INPUT_XML>", argsList, sw);
}
```

Your XSLT could be enhanced like this:

```
...
<xsl:param name="SchemaLocation"/> <!-- this more or less at the top of your XSLT! -->
...

<xsl:template match="/">
   <root version="1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="{$SchemaLocation}">
   ...
   ...
</xsl:template>
....
```